# remove nested text at span right end with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having multiple almost identical span in an html page

```
<span class="title">          
 <span class="icon icon-title" title="Title">Title:</span> 
 <a href="LINK_HERE">PAGE_TITLE_HERE</a> remove this
</span>
```

There are several of such on page in div's and li's of identical classes, the only thing that differs is the `LINK_HERE` and `PAGE_TITLE_HERE`.

What I need to do is remove the `"remove this"` text from the span's. What I managed to do is a clumsy replace solution which looks like this:

```
('div.content').html($('div.content').html().replace(/remove this/g,' '))
```

I'm not exactly happy with this as it replaces all occurences of the words on page and causes certain issues with other code present. If I limit div.content to .title, strange things start to happen - all the occurences of the abovementioned span become copies of the first occurence. I.e.

```
1 remove this
2 remove this
3 remove this
```

turns into

```
1
1
1
```

Could anyone suggest a more elegant solution to remove replace or hide the "remove this" text, perhaps, using .slice or .trim or .remove or a combination of those?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML structure is not proper I think.

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to see the structure, but I may have changed the scope since you seem to be heavily dependent on text nodes in your replace. I strongly suggest you wrap the text in some container and remove the container

Comment: Your code works fine, at least here http://jsfiddle.net/LCUea/3/

Comment: @freebird What do you mean by proper? Do you mean it's not semantic? not optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just remove the last child of `span.title`, since you know that's where the text you want is

http://jsfiddle.net/LCUea/2/

```
$('span.title').each(function(){
  this.removeChild(this.lastChild);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try them out. As for restructuring html it would be my first option, if it was possible. Unfortunately, it is inserted into the html page by a plugin on page render, so it's beyond my reach.

Comment: @EasyLife  I didn't suggest you should restructure your HTML. This code is heavily dependent on the structure of the HTML. Restructuring the HTML to be more semantic has lots of benefits (requiring fewer changes with restructuring), but without understanding why you're doing this, I prefer to just answer the question, it's simple enough

Comment: I know you didn't. I've tried your remove child solution and it worked like a miracle. As the actual text doesn't end in "this", but lets say "it", first I was dumb to change the this.removeChild to it.removeChild. :))   Anyway, it works like a charm and I can't really believe that I don't have to mess with the code anymore or manualy replace "remove it" after pasting it to a text document (the page is a report generator of sorts). So I really, really appreciate your help Juan, and will vote up as soon as I get enough rep to do so!    To everyone else, thanks for your input, appreciate that.

Comment: @EasyLife You can still choose an accepted answer before you get more rep

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the text from your element, you can use `contents` and `filter` methods.

```
$('span.title').contents().filter(function(i){
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
       $(this).remove()
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LCUea/

Comment: Do you think that the html structure can be improved in the question?

Comment: @freebird Well, nesting span elements is not a good way for structuring the markup, I'm not sure what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks , It will be great if you could just let the OP know  about the structure he is currently having.If possible.Thanks.+1 for the answer.

Comment: I edited his question and may have changed the scope of the issue since it seems so reliant on text nodes and their placement

Comment: What about removing anything after the last "a" in span.title ?

Comment: @mplungjan That's my answer, remove the last child of `span.title`, pretty straight forward as I see it

Comment: @freebird Thanks, OP says that markup is generated by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the script only, then you may use it this way:

```
$('span.title').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/remove this/g,' '));
});​​​​​
```

UPDATE: Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LCUea/4/

Now it will remove all the occurence of unwrapped elements in the span '.title', irrespective of the particular text.

JS

```
$('span.title').each(function(){
    //$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/remove this/g,' '));
    var html = '';
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        html += $(this).outerHTML();
    });
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Comment: This replaces HTML that doesn't need to be replaced, it's almost the same hack the OP suggested

Comment: The question says that replacing this text on the whole page ends up in making weird changes to the page. This way at least the replacement is narrowed down.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that it's still hackish, there are two better solutions already here

Comment: Obviously a hack is required for what needs to be done. I have tried to do it a more impressive way, by which all the unwrapped elements will be replaced.

Comment: A hack is not needed, see my answer. You're still replacing HTML that doesn't need replacing